# Text Block Parser

Tags: javascript, parsing, text

So I have a website which has a text box that you can paste a block of text into. That string you entered is stored as a variable. I'm working on a javascript section that parses the string and leaves you with two variables. The part you past in looks something like the bit below.

```
<!-- Note: comment.
Comment/Comment, more comments "comment"-->
<xx:aaa xx:bbb="sss" xx:ccc="SectionA;SectionB;SectionC=SectionD;SectionE=SectionF.SectionG.SectionH;,SectionI=SectionJ;SectionK=SectionL;SectionM=SectionN;SectionO=SectionP.SectionQ.SectionR;SectionS=/;"/>
<vz:aaa xx:bbb="iii" xx:ccc="\SectionT\SectionU\_SectionV,\SectionW\SectionX,\SectionY\_SectionZ"/>
```

So enter the string and after the parse you will have the below variables:

```
varaible1: SectionA;SectionB;SectionC=SectionD;SectionE=SectionF.SectionG.SectionH;,SectionI=SectionJ;SectionK=SectionL;SectionM=SectionN;SectionO=SectionP.SectionQ.SectionR;SectionS=/;
variable2: \SectionT\SectionU\_SectionV,\SectionW\SectionX,\SectionY\_SectionZ
```

I have a basic parser set-up where it replaces \ with commas, but that isn't going to cut it obviously. There needs to be some serious parsing action going on here.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: You need to get the string you entered to return the two variables. Both those parts are explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse the string using a regex:

```js
    var string = 'Note: comment. Comment/Comment, more comments "comment" \
    <xx:aaa xx:bbb="sss" xx:ccc="SectionA;SectionB;SectionC=SectionD;SectionE=SectionF.SectionG.SectionH;,SectionI=SectionJ;SectionK=SectionL;SectionM=SectionN;SectionO=SectionP.SectionQ.SectionR;SectionS=/;"/> \
    <vz:aaa xx:bbb="iii" xx:ccc="\SectionT\SectionU\_SectionV,\SectionW\SectionX,\SectionY\_SectionZ"/>';
    var regex = /xx:ccc=\"([^\>]*)\"\/\>/g;
    var variable1 = regex.exec(string)[1];
    var variable2 = regex.exec(string)[1];
    alert(variable1);
    alert(variable2);
```

`xx:ccc=\"` match against the characters `xx:ccc="`

`([^\>]*)` capture multiple characters that can be anything except a close bracket

`\"\/\>` match against the characters `"/>`

regex.exec returns an array, the first element of which is the match and the second is the first capture group, so you can assign the contents of the capture group to your variables.

Comment: Alright I'll give that a try tomorrow. Will that work if you paste the ENTIRE block of text in it though? Starting from the <!-- comment to the very end at _SectionZ"/>. It has to be able to parse that whole thing. Removing the comment tag and parsing out the rest.

Comment: Yes it works with the comment. Click "Run Code Snippet" for a demonstration. As you can see the from the code the comment is part of the string it is testing.

Comment: Alright so I gave it a go but am still having some issues. I made a Fiddle and shared a collaboration link and a share link to take a look at it.
https://jsfiddle.net/ThePieMonster/xe1wactq/2/#&togetherjs=9ydsEL1kxc
https://jsfiddle.net/ThePieMonster/xe1wactq/2/

Comment: You need to escape the brackets using &lt; and &gt; or the comment etc won't show up: https://jsfiddle.net/h4gx9x2x/

Comment: Hello, again. Sorry for the delay, had a busy weekend. I updated a few things again and something is preventing the fiddle from running.
https://jsfiddle.net/ThePieMonster/ju8zw8qq/3/

Comment: What's wrong with it? I copied the text into the text area and clicked Test it and it parsed and output fine

Comment: Alright never mind then. I guess my IE 11 just can't handle regex anymore. Back to Chrome, lol.